# DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HHmmss") returns month only in deployed location

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting, console-application

Creating a new folder

```
string newFolder = Globals.applicationPath + @"BatchHistory\Batch" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HHmmss") + @"\";
```

In the dev PC everything works as expected folder is named: "Batch12-23-2019 181504"

When deploying the console app to the server the folder name comes out as "Batch12"

Any clue why?

Side details:

- .net framework 4.7.2
- Output type: Console App
- Local dev env: Win10
- Deployed env: WinSrv 2016

> The issue was in fact culture settings on deployed location.

Comment: Folder names cannot include certain characters like either slash variety.  use a dash to get `Batch12-23-2019`

Comment: `/` is an invalid character in folder names. Use `"M-d-yyyy-HHmmss"`.

Comment: Check the regional settings in control panel on both computers and compare.

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HHmmss") is a formatter the output is 
12-23-2019 181504, i have tested using "-" in the tostring method but the same issue appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DateTime.Now.ToString()` method *probably* creates "some" format on your deployed location as well but forward slash (`/`) *can't* be the part of a folder name in Windows.

From: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

> ```
>     The following reserved characters:
>         < (less than)
>         > (greater than)
>         : (colon)
>         " (double quote)
>         / (forward slash)
>         \ (backslash)
>         | (vertical bar or pipe)
>         ? (question mark)
>         * (asterisk)
> ```

It looks like it assigns before the part of "first" `/` character when you tried to name a folder, which is `Batch12` in your case.

Remember, [the `"/"` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of "replace me current culture or supplied culture date separator" on custom date strings. In your dev pc, your [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8)'s [`DateSeparator` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator?view=netframework-4.8) seems - and that's why it's in the resulted string.

That means your deployed server's `CurrentCulture` is using `/` as a `DateSeparator` and that's why it's *still* resulted `/` when you use `ToString` method.

I suggest you to use the same culture settings on your dev and deployed servers. Or you can change your date separator from `/` to `-` in your code like;

```
string newFolder = Globals.applicationPath + @"BatchHistory\Batch" +
                   DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy HHmmss") + @"\";
```

Comment: I have tested replacing the "/" with "-" but same issue, fyi

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGélinas Please re-read my full answer. If you use `/` character and your current or supplied culture's datese parator is not `/`, that `/` character replaced itself with _that_ character.  Replacing `/` with `-` should work since neither it is a reserved character nor it has a special meaning in custom date format strings.

Comment: Hi, thanks the culture settings was the issue, Just to clarify when i was using "-" in the toString it still resulted in the issue, though changing the culture fixed it.